# Regression Answers mismatch between my VBA code and excel regression

Tags: excel, vba, linear-regression

I wrote a regression code in VBA for an array. The output values are different from excel built-in regression function results, after 12 decimal places the results changes due to which it leads to wrong p-values. How can I match my code results with the excel regression function

Below is code which I have written for regression.

```
Sub regression1()

Dim y, x, rsq2, rsq3, SeCo, tstats, Pvalues As Variant
Dim Ubr As Long, Ubc As Long
Dim ii, jj, P, p1, p2, intp2 As Integer
Dim m, rsq1, rvar1 As Variant
Dim Coeff, rvar, rsq, rvar2, rvar3 As Variant
Dim results As Variant

yi = Range("B1:B13")

xi = Range("D1:F13")

Ubr = UBound(xi, 1)
Ubc = UBound(xi, 2)

ReDim x(1 To Ubr - 1, 1 To Ubc + 1)
ReDim y(1 To Ubr - 1, 1 To 1)
ReDim results(1 To 2, 1 To Ubc + Ubc + 4)


    For ii = 1 To Ubr - 1
        x(ii, 1) = 1
    Next ii
    
    For ii = 2 To Ubr
        For jj = 2 To Ubc + 1
            x(ii - 1, jj) = xi(ii, jj - 1)
        Next jj
    Next ii
    
    For ii = 2 To Ubr
        y(ii - 1, 1) = yi(ii, 1)
    Next ii
    
    
    With Application
     m = .MInverse(.MMult(.Transpose(x), x))
     Coeff = .MMult(m, .MMult(.Transpose(x), y))
     rvar1 = Evaluate(.MMult(.Transpose(y), .MMult(x, Coeff)))
     rvar2 = (UBound(x, 1) - UBound(x, 2))
     rvar3 = .SumSq(y)
     rvar = (rvar3 - rvar1) / rvar2
     rsq1 = .MMult(x, Coeff)
     
     ReDim rsq2(1 To Ubr - 1, 1)
     For ii = 1 To Ubr - 1
      rsq2(ii, 1) = y(ii, 1) - rsq1(ii, 1)
     Next ii
     
     ReDim rsq3(1 To Ubr - 1, 1)
     For ii = 1 To Ubr - 1
      rsq3(ii, 1) = y(ii, 1) - .Average(y)
     Next ii
     
     rsq = 1 - (.SumSq(rsq2) / .SumSq(rsq3))
     
     ReDim SeCo(1 To UBound(m, 1), 1 To 1)
     For ii = 1 To UBound(m, 1)
      SeCo(ii, 1) = (rvar * m(ii, ii)) ^ 0.5
     Next ii
     
     ReDim tstats(1 To UBound(m, 1), 1 To 1)
     For ii = 1 To UBound(m, 1)
      tstats(ii, 1) = Coeff(ii, 1) / SeCo(ii, 1)
     Next ii
    End With
            
    With WorksheetFunction
    
    ReDim Pvalues(1 To UBound(m, 1), 1 To 1)
    For ii = 1 To UBound(m, 1)
      Pvalues(ii, 1) = .T_Dist_2T(Abs(tstats(ii, 1)), UBound(y, 1) - 3)
     Next ii
     
    results(1, 1) = "Variables"
    results(1, 2) = "R-Square"
    results(1, 3) = "P-value (intercept)"
    
    For iii = 1 To Ubc
        results(1, iii + 3) = "P-Value" & iii
    Next iii
    
    results(1, 3 + Ubc + 1) = "B0 (Intercept)"
    
    For iii = 1 To Ubc
        results(1, iii + 4 + Ubc) = "B" & iii
    Next iii


Dim Name As Variant
Dim Fname As Variant

Fname = "Inter"
    For iii = 1 To Ubc
    
        Name = xi(1, iii)
    
        Fname = .Concat(Fname, " + ", Name)
    
    Next iii
    
    results(2, 1) = Fname
    
    results(2, 2) = rsq
    
    For iii = 1 To Ubc + 1
    
        results(2, iii + 2) = Pvalues(iii, 1)
    
    Next iii
    
        For iii = 1 To Ubc + 1
    
        results(2, iii + 3 + Ubc) = Coeff(iii, 1)
    
    Next iii
    
    
    End With

Range("I2", Range("I2").Offset(UBound(results, 1) - 1, UBound(results, 2) - 1)) = results

Range("S22", Range("S22").Offset(UBound(m, 1) - 1, 0)) = tstats

Range("V22", Range("V22").Offset(UBound(m, 1) - 1, 0)) = SeCo

End Sub
```

[image: Here is the snippet of the VBA results and Excel regression.]

Note that the regression output from R code is same as excel regression function.

The data used for the above results is as follow

```
y   x1  x2  x3
2.70%    57.0   3   18713
2.90%    68.0   3.3 20877
2.40%    77.0   3.5 21873
2.20%    79.0   3.8 20866
2.10%    81.0   4   20035
2.10%    79.0   4.3 18445
1.70%    75.0   4.5 16773
2.30%    81.0   4.7 17329
2.40%    92.0   4.8 18947
2.80%    88.0   5   17701
3.40%    74.0   5.1 14485
4.30%    86.0   5.2 16440
```

Comment: What was the maths used in the Excel regression function? did you compare that to yours?

Comment: @SolarMike I have used built-in regression function from data analysis in excel (https://www.investopedia.com/ask/answers/062215/how-can-i-run-linear-and-multiple-regressions-excel.asp) and to create a regression code in VBA, I have followed the following link (https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat462/node/132/)

Comment: So built-in function  - what is the maths behind it?

Comment: It's built-in function from Microsoft . I don't have any idea about the maths behind it. If I know the maths I can easily replicate it. However, I have used the Least squares estimates in matrix notation for the multiple linear regression. Attaching the link about Least squares estimates in matrix notation (https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat462/node/132/) @SolarMike

Comment: So if you have no idea of the maths behind the function, then how do you think you can correct your function? Or even, your function might be correct and the built-in one has some drift or error... How can you check?

Comment: Because the regression outputs should have been same. And it is mentioned in the post that the "regression output from R code is same as excel regression function.".

Comment: In VBA *every variable* needs a type when declared.  You can't do this: `Dim a, b, c As Long` - `a` and `b` will be Variants and only `c` will be `Long`.  I'd start by fixing that.

Comment: @TimWilliams changed it as `Dim y As Variant, x As Variant, rsq2 As Variant, rsq3 As Variant, SeCo As Variant, tstats As Variant, Pvalues As Variant
Dim Ubr As Long, Ubc As Long
Dim ii As Integer, jj As Integer, P As Integer, p1 As Integer, p2 As Integer, intp2 As Integer
Dim m As Variant, rsq1 As Variant, rvar1 As Variant
Dim Coeff As Variant, rvar As Variant, rsq As Variant, rvar2 As Variant, rvar3 As Variant
Dim results As Variant` But the results are same.

Comment: Have you tried a similar exercise but with a univariate X? If so, does this show the same drift in the least squares estimates?

Comment: @Solar Mike. The mathematics underlying linear regression calculations is standard. The similarity between the OP results and Excel's suggests to me that the underlying mathematics is not the issue here, but the precision of calculations might be. Personally, I would be looking at comparison of the ANOVA table outputs as the next investigative step.